# Can I use a bootable Ubuntu like a regular Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, operating-systems, liveusb

I need to do some cuda (gpu accelerated) computation with tools only available on linux.

I could install a second OS on my machine but since I've never done it I'm sure I'll just destroy my current windows installation, and I don't want to loose time backing up things and restoring them.

If I make a bootable usb key with rufus/etcher.io of the latest ubuntu ISO, can I then use it as a regular OS? install things, work with them?

Thanks.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD

Answer (score 1):

A Linux Live CD or USB can do anything that is possible for a
disk-based installation, although by necessity it will be slower.
This slowness might not matter if the main processing is done via the GPU
and does not heavily use the disk.

If you are on Windows, you can see this detailed step-by-step
[Ubuntu tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview)
for creating the Live media.
A similar tutorial is available for
[Apple macOS](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview).

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux LiveCD you can do anything you can do on a standard Linux installation, except:

- It will be way slower
- Every time you reboot it will reset to its default state (this might be a dealbreaker)

Answer (score 0):

To use a bootable Ubuntu as a regular installed system, you need to create a persistent live USB. Here is some documentation to achieve your goal:

- [Live Usb Pendrive Persistent](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent)
- [mkusb - tool to create boot drives](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), it can be installed and used from a live system.